# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de varios elementos HTML y convertirlo en un JSON string?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Tengo varios elementos HTML en los cuales obtengo los valores usando JQuery y array:

```js
var trads = $("select[name='personal[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var num_trad = trads.length;

var langs = new Array();
var values = new Array();
var approved = new Array();

for (var i=1; i<=num_trad; i++){
      langs.push($("select[name='lang_"+i+"[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      values.push($("input[name='words_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      values.push($("input[name='approved_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
}

console.log(trads);
console.log(langs);
console.log(values);
```

```css
.divs{float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="personal[]">
     <option value="1001">Mark</option>
     <option value="1002">Rose</option>
    </select>
    
<div style="clear:both;">
 <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_1[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_1[]" value="302">
    <input name="approved_1[]" value="yes">
 </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">
  <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_1[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_1[]" value="180">
    <input name="approved_1[]" value="no">
 </div>
</div>

<hr style="clear: both;">
<select name="personal[]">
     <option value="1001">Mark</option>
     <option value="1002" selected>Rose</option>
    </select>
    
<div style="clear:both;">
 <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_2[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_2[]" value="236">
    <input name="approved_2[]" value="yes">
 </div>
</div>

<hr style="clear: both;">
```

Como se muestra en el resultado se muestra de manera separada y me gustaría ordenar estos valores como un JSON string obteniendo algo similar como esto:

"1001":{
      content:[{
        language: "English",
        words: "302",
        approved: "yes"
      },
      {
        language: "Spanish",
        words: "180",
        approved: "no"
      }]
    },
    "1002":{
      content:[{
        language: "Spanish",
        words: "236",
        approved: "yes"
      }]
    }

¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que el json resultante quede como quieres puedes colocar los valores en una cadena concatenandolos usando plantillas de cadenas, también necesitas un `for` que recorra el array de personal y otro que recorra los lenguajes que tiene para que queden separados, cuidando que estén definidos:

El código queda funcionando de la siguiente forma:

```js
var trads = $("select[name='personal[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var num_trad = trads.length;

var langs = new Array();
var values = new Array();
var approved = new Array();

for (var i=1; i<=num_trad; i++){
      langs.push($("select[name='lang_"+i+"[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      values.push($("input[name='words_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      approved.push($("input[name='approved_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
}

//console.log(trads);
//console.log(langs);
//console.log(values);
var lenguajes=2;

var sjson=`[`;
for (var i=0; i<num_trad; i++){
  sjson+=`{"personal": "${trads[i]}","content": [`;
  for(var h=0; h<lenguajes&&langs[i][h]!=undefined; h++){
    sjson+=`{"language":"${langs[i][h]}",`;
    sjson+=`"words":"${values[i][h]}",`;
    sjson+=`"approved":"${approved[i][h]}"}`;
    if(langs[i][h+1]!=undefined)
      sjson+=',';      
  }
  sjson+=']}';      
  if(i+1<num_trad)
    sjson+=',';
}
sjson+=']';
console.log(sjson);
```

```css
.divs{float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="personal[]">
     <option value="1001">Mark</option>
     <option value="1002">Rose</option>
    </select>
    
<div style="clear:both;">
 <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_1[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_1[]" value="302">
    <input name="approved_1[]" value="yes">
 </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">
  <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_1[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_1[]" value="180">
    <input name="approved_1[]" value="no">
 </div>
</div>

<hr style="clear: both;">
<select name="personal[]">
     <option value="1001">Mark</option>
     <option value="1002" selected>Rose</option>
    </select>
    
<div style="clear:both;">
 <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_2[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_2[]" value="236">
    <input name="approved_2[]" value="yes">
 </div>
</div>

<hr style="clear: both;">
```

y este es el resultado:

```
[{
    "personal": "1001",
    "content": [{
        "language": "English",
        "words": "302",
        "approved": "yes"
    }, {
        "language": "Spanish",
        "words": "180",
        "approved": "no"
    }]
}, {
    "personal": "1002",
    "content": [{
        "language": "Spanish",
        "words": "236",
        "approved": "yes"
    }]
}]
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de probar el código y funciona. Tengo una consulta, el valor de la variable `lenguajes` es la cantidad de idiomas de los select, sin embargo, si hubiese el caso de que esta cantidad de idiomas variara, ¿Cómo sería en ese caso?

Comment: @NekoLopez si lo puse para ese caso, si tuvieras mas lenguajes solo tendrías que cambiar ese número

Comment: Ok, lo tengo claro. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

He incluido una rutina adicional para que la salida sea de tipo JSON en tu codigo, espero que pueda servirte.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <select name="personal[]">
             <option value="1001">Mark</option>
             <option value="1002">Rose</option>
            </select>
            
        <div style="clear:both;">
         <div class="divs">
            <select name="lang_1[]">
             <option value="English">English</option>
             <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="divs">
            <input name="words_1[]" value="302">
            <input name="approved_1[]" value="yes">
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <div style="clear:both;">
          <div class="divs">
            <select name="lang_1[]">
             <option value="English">English</option>
             <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="divs">
            <input name="words_1[]" value="180">
            <input name="approved_1[]" value="no">
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <hr style="clear: both;">
        <select name="personal[]">
             <option value="1001">Mark</option>
             <option value="1002" selected>Rose</option>
            </select>
            
        <div style="clear:both;">
         <div class="divs">
            <select name="lang_2[]">
             <option value="English">English</option>
             <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="divs">
            <input name="words_2[]" value="236">
            <input name="approved_2[]" value="yes">
         </div>
        </div>
        
        <hr style="clear: both;">
        <span id="res"> nada</span>

        <script>
            var trads = $("select[name='personal[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var num_trad = trads.length;

            var langs = new Array();
            var values = new Array();
            var approved = new Array();

            for (var i=1; i<=num_trad; i++){
                langs.push($("select[name='lang_"+i+"[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
                values.push($("input[name='words_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
                approved.push($("input[name='approved_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
            }
            
            /*
            console.log(trads);
            console.log(langs);
            console.log(values);
            console.log(approved);
            */ 
            
            // ----------------------------------------------
            // listado de arreglo para json
            var arreglo = new Array();

            // carga de valores
            for (var i = 0; i < trads.length; i++) {
               var list = {   'trads'   : trads[i],
                              'content' :[]
                          };
                           // guardas los datos del array       
                                 list['content'].push({
                                 "language": langs[i].toString(),
                                 "words":   values[i].toString(),
                                 "approved": approved[i].toString()
                              });
              arreglo.push(list);
            }
            
            json = JSON.stringify(arreglo); // aqui tienes la lista de objetos en Json            
            $("#res").text('' + json ); // salida ver resultado
            // ----------------------------------------------------------
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Los arreglos se unifican para generar una salida tipo JSON como esta:

```
[{"trads":"1001","content": 
[{"language":"English,Spanish","words":"302,180","approved":"yes,no"}]}, 
 {"trads":"1002","content": 
[{"language":"Spanish","words":"236","approved":"yes"}]}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero quisiera que los idiomas estén por separado como en el ejemplo que puse en la pregunta, ¿Cómo sería en ese caso?