# ¿Cómo evitar las comillas en un JSON obtenido con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

De acuerdo a esta pregunta ([link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/284440/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-los-valores-de-varios-elementos-html-y-convertirlo-en-un-json-stri)) tengo un JSON con valores que extraigo de elementos HTML con la diferencia de usar `<textarea>` en lugar de `<select>` y cuyos valores se obtienen de textos de archivos de MS Word. Construyo mi JSON de la siguiente manera:

```
var trads = $("select[name='personal[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var num_trad = trads.length;

var text = new Array();
var values = new Array();
var approved = new Array();

for (var i=1; i<=num_trad; i++){
  text.push($("textarea[name='lang_"+i+"[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
  values.push($("input[name='words_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
  approved.push($("input[name='approved_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
}

var lenguajes=10;

var sjson=`[`;
for (var i=0; i<num_trad; i++){
  sjson+=`{"personal": "${trads[i]}","content": [`;
  for(var h=0; h<lenguajes&&langs[i][h]!=undefined; h++){
    sjson+=`{"text":"${langs[i][h]}",`;
    sjson+=`"words":"${values[i][h]}",`;
    sjson+=`"approved":"${approved[i][h]}"}`;
    if(langs[i][h+1]!=undefined)
      sjson+=',';      
 }
 sjson+=']}';      
 if(i+1<num_trad)
   sjson+=',';
}
sjson+=']';
console.log(sjson);
```

Sin embargo, algunos documentos de Word contienen texto con comillas y al incorporarlo en el JSON me presenta un error, por ejemplo:

```
[{
   "personal": "1001",
   "content": [{
      "text": "Los lenguajes que mencionó son: "Español e Inglés"",
      "words": "302",
      "approved": "yes"
   }, {
      "text": "Ella dijo: "Me gustan los helados"",
      "words": "180",
      "approved": "no"
   }]
}]
```

El cual es un JSON no valido.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Comment: Sabes cuales son los textos que llegan en comillas ? si sabes extactamente cuales son los texto , lo que puedes hacer es remplazar las comillas dobles de los texto por comillas simpres de esta forma: `"text": "Ella dijo: 'Me gustan los helados'",`

Comment: Lamentablemente no se que textos tendrán comillas :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen 2 opciones:

**1. Remplazar las comillas dobles con comillas simples:**

Para esto puedes usar `split()` y `join()` de la siguiente forma:

```
cadena.split('"').join("'");
```

resultado:

```
[{
   "personal": "1001",
   "content": [{
      "text": "Los lenguajes que mencionó son: 'Español e Inglés'",
      "words": "302",
      "approved": "yes"
   }, {
      "text": "Ella dijo: 'Me gustan los helados'",
      "words": "180",
      "approved": "no"
   }]
}]
```

Puedes ver como funciona en el siguiente código:

```js
var trads = $("select[name='personal[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var num_trad = trads.length;

var langs = new Array();
var values = new Array();
var approved = new Array();

for (var i=1; i<=num_trad; i++){
      langs.push($("select[name='lang_"+i+"[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      values.push($("input[name='words_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      approved.push($("input[name='approved_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
}

var lenguajes=2;

var sjson=`[`;
for (var i=0; i<num_trad; i++){
  sjson+=`{"personal": "${trads[i]}","content": [`;
  for(var h=0; h<lenguajes&&langs[i][h]!=undefined; h++){
    sjson+=`{"language":"${langs[i][h].split('"').join("'")}",`;
    sjson+=`"words":"${values[i][h]}",`;
    sjson+=`"approved":"${approved[i][h]}"}`;
    if(langs[i][h+1]!=undefined)
      sjson+=',';      
  }
  sjson+=']}';      
  if(i+1<num_trad)
    sjson+=',';
}
sjson+=']';
console.log(sjson);
```

```css
.divs{float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="personal[]">
     <option value="1001">Mark</option>
     <option value="1002">Rose</option>
    </select>
    
<div style="clear:both;">
 <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_1[]">
     <option value='Los lenguajes que mencionó son: "Español e Inglés"'>English</option>
     <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_1[]" value="302">
    <input name="approved_1[]" value="yes">
 </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">
  <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_1[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_1[]" value="180">
    <input name="approved_1[]" value="no">
 </div>
</div>

<hr style="clear: both;">
<select name="personal[]">
     <option value="1001">Mark</option>
     <option value="1002" selected>Rose</option>
    </select>
    
<div style="clear:both;">
 <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_2[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_2[]" value="236">
    <input name="approved_2[]" value="yes">
 </div>
</div>

<hr style="clear: both;">
```

**2. Remplazar las comillas dobles y agregar una barra invertida:**

Para esto también puedes usar `split()` y `join()` de la siguiente forma:

```
cadena.split('"').join('\\\"');
```

resultado:

```
[{
   "personal": "1001",
   "content": [{
      "text": "Los lenguajes que mencionó son: \"Español e Inglés\"",
      "words": "302",
      "approved": "yes"
   }, {
      "text": "Ella dijo: \"Me gustan los helados\"",
      "words": "180",
      "approved": "no"
   }]
}]
```

La ventaja de este método es que se mantendrán las comillas dobles al mostrar el texto.

Puedes ver como funciona en el siguiente código:

```js
var trads = $("select[name='personal[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
var num_trad = trads.length;

var langs = new Array();
var values = new Array();
var approved = new Array();

for (var i=1; i<=num_trad; i++){
      langs.push($("select[name='lang_"+i+"[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      values.push($("input[name='words_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
      approved.push($("input[name='approved_"+i+"[]'").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get());
}

var lenguajes=2;

var sjson=`[`;
for (var i=0; i<num_trad; i++){
  sjson+=`{"personal": "${trads[i]}","content": [`;
  for(var h=0; h<lenguajes&&langs[i][h]!=undefined; h++){
    sjson+=`{"language":"${langs[i][h].split('"').join('\\\"')}",`;
    sjson+=`"words":"${values[i][h]}",`;
    sjson+=`"approved":"${approved[i][h]}"}`;
    if(langs[i][h+1]!=undefined)
      sjson+=',';      
  }
  sjson+=']}';      
  if(i+1<num_trad)
    sjson+=',';
}
sjson+=']';
console.log(sjson);
```

```css
.divs{float:left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="personal[]">
     <option value="1001">Mark</option>
     <option value="1002">Rose</option>
    </select>
    
<div style="clear:both;">
 <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_1[]">
     <option value='Los lenguajes que mencionó son: "Español e Inglés"'>English</option>
     <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_1[]" value="302">
    <input name="approved_1[]" value="yes">
 </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">
  <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_1[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_1[]" value="180">
    <input name="approved_1[]" value="no">
 </div>
</div>

<hr style="clear: both;">
<select name="personal[]">
     <option value="1001">Mark</option>
     <option value="1002" selected>Rose</option>
    </select>
    
<div style="clear:both;">
 <div class="divs">
    <select name="lang_2[]">
     <option value="English">English</option>
     <option value="Spanish" selected>Spanish</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div class="divs">
    <input name="words_2[]" value="236">
    <input name="approved_2[]" value="yes">
 </div>
</div>

<hr style="clear: both;">
```

Puedes comprobar (con https://jsonlint.com/ por ejemplo) que en ambos casos los json son validos.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Genial, me salvaste la vida! :D

Comment: @NekoLopez de nada, que tengas buen día.